# Defining a mapping which rotates a plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $n = (n_1, n_2, n_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \left\{0\right\}$. I want to define a linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x)=Ax$, which maps the xy-plane $z = 0$ to the plane
$$n_1 x+n_2 y+n_3z =0,$$
i.e., rotates the xy-plane so that the resulting plane has the normal vector $n$ and still contains the origin.

However, I am unable to derive a general formula for the rotation matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$. As $e_1 = (1, 0, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1, 0)$ span the xy-plane, $Ae_1$ and $Ae_2$ span the rotated plane. I suppose that one could use the properties
$$Ae_1 \times Ae_2 = n,$$
$$Ae_1 \cdot Ae_2 =e_1^T A^T A e_2 = 0,$$
and
$$\Vert Ae_1 \Vert = \Vert Ae_2 \Vert = 1,$$
but the derivation of $A$ seems to become very complicated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a vector that is orthogonal to $N = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$, for example,

$V = (- n_2, n_1, 0) $

and define $W$ as follows

$W = N \times V = (n_1, n_2, n_3) \times (-n_2, n_1, 0) $

Then

$ W = (- n_1 n_3 , - n_2 n_3, n_1^2 + n_2^2 ) $

Next normalize both $V$ and $W$ to obtain $u_1$ and $u_2$ , i.e.

$ u_1 = \dfrac{V}{\| V \| } $

$ u_2 = \dfrac{W}{\| W \| } $

also normalize $N$ to obtain $u_3$

$ u_3 = \dfrac{N}{ \| N \| } $

Now the matrix $A$ is simply given by

$ A = [u_1, u_2, u_3] $